# Double point appearing in section head in Context

Tags: sectioning, context, section-titles

After applying the solution from [here](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/References#Adjusting_the_separator_in_between_the_referenced_prefixes) for referencing without dots in the text, the section heading doubles the point between chapter and section numbers:

[image]

```
\setuphead[chapter][
    alternative=middle, 
    style={\tfb\bf},
    after={\blank[24pt]},
    ]


\defineprocessor[dostopper][right=.]
\defineprocessor[nostopper][right=]

\defineconversionset[stopperconversionyes][][dostopper->n]
\defineconversionset[stopperconversionnop][][nostopper->n]

\setuphead[section][sectionconversionset=stopperconversionyes]

%\setupreferencestructureprefix[section][default][prefixconversionset=stopperconversionnop]
\setupreferencestructureprefix[default][prefixconversionset=stopperconversionnop]

\starttext

\chapter{asdf}
\section[one]{First heading}

In \in{section}[one] we learn.

\stoptext
```

It works alright with chapters in this case, and with sections if I don't use chapters in the text.

Comment: Since Wolfgang's post is quite old (2013) I commented out all those `defineconversionset` lines and after compilation got `1.1 First heading  In 1.1 we learn`. Is this what you want to get?

Comment: @sztruks is right. You don't need those conversions anymore.

Comment: @sztruks, not actually. I though of the possibility of adding a dot after the section number thus: `1.1.` It does look odd, but the original idea was to use it with `sectionsegments=section:*`. In this case, it works, too: `1. Section xxx`. Maybe it's a feature; after all, numbering sections like `1.1.` (with the last dot) is weird and ugly.

Comment: In the linked code the conversion is applied to the `chapter` number but when you apply it to a `section` the stopper is added to *each* number, which results in two periods (the stopper plus the separator between the numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want section numbers to end with a dot, but dotless references. In such a case you only need to call the `numbercommand` key to add whatever you need: `\groupedcommand{}{.}` comes in handy and you don't need to define an *ad hoc* macro just to add a dot.

```
\setuphead[chapter][
    alternative=middle, 
    style={\tfb\bf},
    after={\blank[24pt]},
    ]

%\groupedcommand{#before}{#after}{#content}
\setuphead[section][numbercommand={\groupedcommand{}{.}}]
\starttext

\chapter{Capítulo}
\section[one]{Primer encabezado}

En la \in{sección}[one] aprenderemos.

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jairo. Works like a charm. I'd never thought about using `\groupedcommand` this way -- I assumed it would work exactly like `sectionstopper`.

Comment: @BlackBird `sectionstopper` will affect references too. What I did is appending a dot _after_ the section number is typeset (`numbercommand` won't alter references, only the result shown next to the section title).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution from the [Wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Dotted_number_in_caption):

```
\def\Dot#1{#1.}
\setuphead[section][numbercommand=\Dot]
\setuplist[section][numbercommand=\Dot]
\setuplist[subsection][numbercommand=\Dot]
\setuplist[subsubsection][numbercommand=\Dot]

\starttext

\completecontent

\section{abc}
\subsection{def}

\stoptext
```